# Getting all the combinations of a list of lists of values (or array of arrays) [Cartesian Product]

Tags: list, combinations

I have a list of lists of parameters and I want to combine them in all possible combinations. 
I don't know before the execution the number of lists and the values specified in each list.
This problem is defined and discussed in [Cartesian_Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

A problem input can be stored in array of arrays of values (or list of lists). An example could be two decks of cards. There are two decks `[Red, Blue]`, each deck has 4 card suits `[♠, ♥, ♦, ♣]` and for each suit there are 13 cards `[Ace, King, Queen, Jack, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`.

The Cartesian product of these arrays returns a 104-element set consisting of 2 decks of 52 possible playing cards:

```
[[Red, ♠, Ace], [Red, ♠, King], ..., (Red, ♠, 2), (Red, ♥, Ace), ..., (Red, ♣, 2), 
[Blue, ♠, Ace],[Blue, ♠, King], ..., (Blue, ♠, 2), (Blue, ♥, Ace), ..., (Blue, ♣, 2)]
```

So how generate all possible combinations of a list of lists of values?

Answer (score 0):

Here, a solution written in Javascript.

A possible input of the problem:

```
var parameterList = [ [ 'Red', 'Blue' ],
                [ '\u2660', '\u2665', '\u2666', '\u2663' ],
                [ 'Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 ] ];
```

Calculate the number of combinations

```
var num_comb = 1;
for ( var i = 0; i < parameterList.length; i++)
    num_comb *= parameterList[i].length;
```

Generation of all possible combinations:

```
// index used to store the positions of the combination just generated
var index = new Array(parameterList.length);
for ( var i = 0; i < parameterList.length; i++)
  index[i] = 0;

//array of arrays that will store the final result (i.e., all possible combinations)
var combinationsList = [];

do {
  var temp = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
    temp[i] = parameterList[i][index[i]];
  combinationsList.push(temp);
} while (nextIndex());


function nextIndex() {
  var carryover = true;
  for ( var i = parameterList.length - 1; i >= 0 && carryover; i--) {
    index[i] = (index[i] + 1) % parameterList[i].length;
    if (index[i] != 0)
      carryover = false;
  }
//if 'carryover' is true and 'i' is equal to zero means that all possible combinations 
//have been generated. In this case 'nextIndex' is equal to the first combination.
  return !carryover;
}

var allCombString = printCombinationsList();
```

For printing all the combinations:

```
function printCombinationsList() {
  var ret = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i < combinationsList.length; i++) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < combinationsList[i].length; j++)
      ret += ((j == 0) ? "[" : "") + combinationsList[i][j] + ((j == combinationsList[i].length - 1) ? "]": ", ");
    ret += "<br/>";
  }
return ret;
}
```